# Unknown CMake command "create_single_source_cgal_program"

Tags: c++, cmake, cgal

I have been trying to install CGAL on Ubuntu through a VirtualBox for a while, every time I run the command

```
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DCGAL_DIR=/cgal
```

on an example, I get the following message(with no other errors):

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:12 (create_single_source_cgal_program):
  Unknown CMake command "create_single_source_cgal_program".


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/botengu/cgal/Bounding_volumes/examples/Min_sphere_d/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

I have seen the other similar topics on the page, they either differed a bit or they weren't answered. I'd like anyone to help solve this problem.

Comment: "I have been trynig to install CGAL" - It looks like you want to build an **example** for CGAL, located in `Bounding_volumes/examples/Min_sphere_d/` subdirectory. And `CGAL_DIR` should point to the **installation directory** of CGAL itself. Please, describe how have you installed CGAL.

Comment: Which version of cgal ?

Comment: the most recent one, 5.0

Comment: For the installation process, everything was done on the terminal, these are the commands I ran: 
- git clone https://github.com/CGAL/cgal 
- sudo apt-get install libcgal-qt5-dev
- sudo apt-get install libqt5svg5-dev

Answer (score 4):

You may also have to run:

cgal_create_CMakeLists

to fix errors in CMakeLists

Answer (score 0):

I've solved my problem, all I had to do was to add more info about the directory of cgal. I replaced the original command with:

cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DCGAL_DIR=~/cgal